# В параметр записывается аргумент в виде строки. Как мне из него получить дату?

Tags: javascript, время

```js
function setDate(obj, year) {
  obj.date = new Date(year);
}

var obj = {}
setDate(obj, "2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0");
console.log(obj.date + '');
```

Comment: а в каком формате нужна дата?

Comment: YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - в формате объекта типа `Date` :)

Comment: @YURII а почему ты решил передавать как строку `"2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0"` ?  C чем связано такое решение?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как еще можно передать ?

Comment: @YURII почему вопросом на вопрос?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Связано с тем , что я не знаю как по другому передать

Comment: @YURII а откуда берутся эти числа? секунды имеют значение? потому что как минимум вот это `new Data(...[2011,0,1,0,0,0,0])` уже даст нужный результат....... и вот этот `new Date('1 1 2011');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

```js
function setDate(obj, strDate) {
  var parts = strDate.split(",");
  obj.date = new Date(
    +parts[0].trim(), +parts[1].trim(), +parts[2].trim(), // date
    +parts[3].trim(), +parts[4].trim(), +parts[5].trim(), +parts[6].trim() // time
  );
}

var Building = {};
setDate(Building, "2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0");
console.log(Building);
```

Comment: Ответ-то не такой какой должен быть... проще было произвести  ̶о̶б̶р̶е̶з̶а̶н̶и̶е̶  конкатенацию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хм, **мой** ответ должен был быть именно таким. В противном случае, откуда же я его взял?

Comment: Ну `YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` не тоже самое что `YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:sssZ`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не ходок в сторону обсуждения разницы между объектом `Date` и строкой с датой в каком-нибудь формате. В вопросе: "как получить дату".

Comment: Наверное для этого и существуют комментарии, чтобы уточнить что-то, правда?) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735732/%D0%92-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83#comment1120502_735732

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы запутали ТС Вашим вопросом о формате. Никакого формата нет. В коде вопроса автор пытается создать объект типа `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность использовать ES6, то можно так:

```js
function setDate(obj, year) {
  obj.date = new Date(...year.match(/\d+/g));
}

var obj = {}
setDate(obj, "2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0");
console.log(obj.date + '');
```

Comment: Семь часов вечера 31-го декабря, идет интенсивная подготовка к встрече Нового Года.

Comment: @Igor, не понял...

Comment: Пардон, у меня в голове это казалось смешной шуткой.

Comment: @Igor, кстати, у меня 3 ночи 1 января выводится...

Comment: А-а-а, я же в EST - Eastern Standard Time. У Вас, значит, Новый Год уже наступил.

Comment: Блин.. Я флаг `g` забыл. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите всего лишь строку превратить в тип `Date`:

*ES6*

```js
function setDate(obj, year) {  
  obj.date = new Date(...year.split(','));  
}

var obj = {}
setDate(obj, "2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0");
console.log(obj.date + '');
```

Comment: Почти как мой... Без ES6 печалька с этим вариантом...

Comment: угу. вообще я его раньше придумал)) Просто Igor меня убедил, что нужно не строку в формате YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss, а объект

Answer (score 0):

```js
function d2(x) {
  return x<10 ? '0' + x : x;
}

function setDate(obj, year) {
  obj.date = new Date(year.replace(
    /^(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)$/,
    function (match, y, M, d, H, m, s, z) {
      return y + '-' + d2(+M+1) + '-' + d2(d) + 'T' + d2(H) + ':' + d2(m) + ':' + d2(s) + '.' + z;
    }
  ));
}

var obj = {}
setDate(obj, "2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0");
console.log(obj.date + '');
```